# Hard steering on 2001 Lexus ES300

Tags: steering, lexus

Went to mechanic a month ago and need sway bars and new brakes. The last two days it's been very difficult to steer when turning but my tires are fine and I just replace power steering fluid but I'm still having difficulties. Any ideas what could be wrong?
2001 Lexus es300

Comment: Is there any noise (whine) when turning the wheel? This would be most noticeable at lower speeds.

Comment: "*I just replace power steering fluid*"...do you mean you filled a low reservoir? Or did you actually drain and replaced the fluid?

Answer (score 2):

Check the belts on the front of the engine. It's likely you have a slipping power steering or accessory belt. The belt could have stretched, or the tensioner could have failed. Replacing a belt is usually pretty straightforward, replacing the tensioner is a little more involved. If the belt seems loose, you may be able to tighten it using a tensioner (possibly part of the power steering pump assembly, or a simple external pulley). I'd check YouTube for videos first, then possibly see if you can find a repair manual for your car if the videos don't help.